# The socket set that I bought has a security lock which I'm unable to open

Tags: tools

I bought a socket set toolbox today and I'm trying to open it but it has some kind of a security lock on the box. I have attached photos of the security lock.

Please help me open this box.

[image: side view]

[image: top view]

[image: side view]

[image: bottom view]

Comment: Cut it off with a sharp knife.

Comment: Scissors or a utility knife, it's just a piece of plastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snip off the head of the "rivet" with a pair of diagonal cutting pliers. Even smaller electronics type diagonal cutters should reach in and cut of the head.

Answer (score 2):

Many options:

Grind it off, dremel or similar

Drill it out,

Split the case and use a saw blade to cut the “lock” piece

Cut the case plastic around the lock - unless you need it in the future to stop other having access...